# Estimate the Flux Linkage of a PMSM Motor

Tags: motor, magnetic-flux

I'm not sure if it is possible to estimate the flux linkage of a PMSM motor (star connection) by the controller itself, where I can measure the input voltage, all the phase currents and the velocity. Measurements of R and L are also available.

The flux linkage is defined as:

$$
\lambda_m = \sqrt{2/3} \frac{2}{P} K_b
$$

Where P=Number of Poles and Kb theback EMF constant. So I need to come up with Kb first, but I don't know how I could achieve this. When I turn on the power supply to speed up the motor to a constant speed, I cannot measure the back EMF, because I can only measure the input voltage. Is it even possible to measure the flux linkage with this setup?

Comment: Can't you measure back-emf by measuring the voltage over the running but (temporarily) disconnected motor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed possible, to do so take a look at the work done in the following paper:
[Sensorless Adaptive Speed Control for PMSM Drives](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5559258)

Within this paper it is explained how to get the flux linkeage. Afterwards it is shown how to estimate this flux variation to estimate the rotor speed:

[image]